# DHCP address 255.255.255.255

Tags: c#, networking, dhcp

I'm using the following code to get DHCP server address from one of my network interfaces:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface networkInterface;

// ... get one of the network interfaces

var properties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
var addresses = properties.DhcpServerAddresses;
```

My network interface is set to a fixed address (not assigned by DHCP) and I'm getting one address from that code, it's 255.255.255.255. Anybody can tell me why? And how can I check if a network interface uses a DHCP or fixed address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address `255.255.255.255` is a broadcast address, which is used by the DHCP protocol to broadcast availability packets. When you're not using DHCP this is the address assigned as a DHCP server, because it will allow the network to automatically discover any DHCP servers (usually routers) on the network.

You can use this to check for DHCP:

```
bool isDhcp = networkInterface.GetIPProperties()
                              .GetIPv4Properties()
                              .IsDhcpEnabled;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I'll mark your response as the answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a 'real' IP address as it can't be assigned to a host. It simply means "broadcast everywhere".

I think it's safe to assume that when you find 255.255.255.255 as DHCP server address, the adapter you're querying has a fixed IP address, or [APIPA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220874) (which happens when an adapter is set as DHCP client, but no DHCP server has responded for a preset period of time).

But the `IsDhcpEnabled` property that @Polynomial mentions is safer to rely on.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I always wondered if there's any reasoning behind 169.x.x.x addresses :).